# jQuery - get form elements by container id

Tags: jquery, forms, element

Which is the easiest way to get all form elements which are contained by a wrapper element.

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input name="elementA" />
  <div id="wrapper">
    <input name="elementB" />
    <textarea name="elementC" />
  </div>
</form>
```

In the above HTML I would elementB and elementC but not elementA. I do not want to list all form element types (select,textarea,input,option...). I would prefer to use myForm.elements.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the `:input` pseudo selector if you don't want to specify them all:

```
$('#wrapper :input');
```

`:input` selects all input, textarea, select and button elements. And there's no need to use `.children()` here.

Comment: I really need to look at more of the pseudo selectors. That's twice someone has come up with a better solution because I don't know them all :)

Comment: Yes it is :), I do not know why I believed it was only for input elements...like :reset :radio...

Comment: @ungarida: Because `input` and `:input` are only one character different, but the later includes all form control types.

Comment: Great answer, more on the :input selector here [jQuery api :input](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)

Comment: This also works, to find the form elements in multiple layers inside the wrapper... $('#wrapper').find(':input'); This will look for inputs inside child elements or wrappers inside the wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

If there are nothing but form elements in it

```
$('#wrapper').children();
```

If there are going to be other things as well

```
$('#wrapper').children( 'input, select, textarea' );
```

Comment: what about `<input name="elementA" />` that will not be found

Comment: He says "I would elementB and elementc but not elementA". In the beginning he asked for form elements within the container.

Comment: Yes it is the second case. But I would prefer have no to do the list 'input, select, textarea' because I'm worried to not consider some form element type. Is there a way ti use form.elements array instead?

Comment: you're right, sorry, I have missed this
@ungarida: no, there is no easier way without a plugin

Answer (score 0):

jQuery('form[name=myform] div#wrapper').children();

Comment: do you want to find elementA as well. Try the code here it shouldnt be

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
$(form)[0].elements
```

I Know above code works in Chrome. Not test other browsers.